# Template directive calling another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I am developing a multi data app that is using angular.js and d3.js. I am having a hard time to include the <svg> into my scope.

What is happening now is that the directive ngTests is being loaded before the ngRepeat executes it's methods.

I am putting the fiddle here so you guys can have a better idea.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marceloduende/qrudH/)

```
<ng-chart></ng-chart>
```

**PS**: I can get the td id on my ngTests directive, but it doesn't update at all `<td ng-tests id="histogram{{$index}}"`.

If I change this line to `<td ng-tests id="histogram">`, use histogram as ID on my directive and change my ngTests directive to read only "#histogram" it creates my svg 6 times on the first table of my ngRepeat, which is not the result I am expecting.

Thank you.

Comment: You would get an answer quicker if you will have a workable fiddle :) As for this problem - I assume you don't need to pass id to ngTests directive you can use element[0] as a dom target for d3.select

Answer (score 0):

Do two things. In your ngChart directive you have the index attribute specified like `index="index"` but it needs to be `index="{{$index}}"`. Then, to read the attribute value from the other directive, instead of accessing the attribute directly like `attrs.index` you should be using `attrs.$observe` more like the following:

```
    attrs.$observe('index', function(observedIndex) {
        console.log('observedIndex:', observedIndex);
    });
```

This way when the index is changed (e.g. by another directive) you get notified and can update the element's text. I forked the fiddle and got it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/activescott/sZqhc/).